# Gulp Cordova build android error - node_modules - gulp-jscs - index.js:99 :- RangeError: Invalid string length

Tags: android, cordova, build, gulp, hybrid-mobile-app

```
this.emit('error', new gutil.PluginError('gulp-jscs', out.join('\n\n'), {

  ^
```

RangeError: Invalid string length

```
 at Array.join (native)
    at DestroyableTransform._flush (C:\ABC\node_modules\gulp-jscs\index.j
s:99:62)
    at DestroyableTransform.<anonymous> (C:\ABC\node_modules\gulp-jscs\no
de_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:135:12
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add try & catch block**
  , function (cb) {

```
    if (out.length > 0) {
        try {
            console.log('out is: ', out[1]);
            this.emit('error', new gutil.PluginError('gulp-jscs', out.join('\n\n'), {
                showStack: false
            }));
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('exception: ', e);
        }
    }

    cb();
})
```